# apply multiple functions in sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I have a list of .stat files in tmp directory.

sample:

**a.stat=>**

```
abc,10

abc,20

abc,30
```

**b.stat=>**

```
xyz,10

xyz,30

xyz,70
```

and so on

I need to find summary of all .stat files.
Currently I am using
`filelist<-list.files(path="/tmp/",pattern=".stat")`

`data<-sapply(paste("/tmp/",filelist,sep=''), read.csv, header=FALSE)`

However I need to apply summary to all files being read. Or simply in n number of .stat files I need summary from 2nd column column

using

`data<-sapply(paste("/tmp/",filelist,sep=''), summary, read.csv, header=FALSE)` does not work and gives me summary with class character, which is no what I intend.

`sapply(filelist, function(filename){df <- read.csv(filename, header=F);print(summary(df[,2]))})` works fine. However my overall objective is to find values that are more than 2 standard deviations away on either side (outliers). So I use sd, but at the same time need to check if all values in the file currently read come under 2SD range.

Comment: `sapply(filelist, function(filename){df <- read.csv(filename, header=F);print(summary(df[,2]))})` ?

Comment: If you need the summary of 2nd column, `summary(sapply(lst, "[[", 2))`

Answer (score 12):

To apply multiple functions at once:

```
f <- function(x){
  list(sum(x),mean(x))
}
sapply(x, f)
```

In your case you want to apply them sequentially, so first read csv data then do summary:

```
sapply(lapply(paste("/tmp/",filelist,sep=''), read.csv), summary)
```

To subset your datasets to run summary on particular column you can use change outer sapply function from `summary` to `function(x) summary(x[[2]])`.

Comment: This mostly worked for me, but why I am getting an extra row? 11 and 81 in below example
[[1]]
abc 
              11 

[[2]]
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
2267000 2267000 3253000 2805000 3253000 3253000 

[[3]]
xyz
           81 

[[4]]
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 348000  645900  665200  649800  665200  963200

Comment: @user1977867 Because this does not apply the functions sequentially, it applies the first function to produce the first row and the second function to produce the second row.

Answer (score 5):

For short functions you don't want to save in the environment, it can also just be done within the sapply call. For @flxflks 's example:

```
sapply(df, function(x) c(min = min(x), avg = mean(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Jangorecki, I changed the function to include a vector and not a list. Only then it worked for me. I am unsure why my function worked and not the other.

```r
f <- function(x){
  c(min = min(x), avg = mean(x))
}
sapply(df, f)
```

I found the solution at https://www.r-bloggers.com/applying-multiple-functions-to-data-frame/