# List of mean, median and sd for a given variable in R

Tags: r, function, apply

Is it possible to give the argument FUN in apply more than one argument? Im trying to get a list of the mean, median and sd of a given variable in any dataframe.
Example: `apply(X = mtcars, MARGIN = mtcars[i], FUN = c(mean, median, sd)` , where *i* is the variable (or column) of interest. Im not sure if this is the method to use, if not, please guide me to a more suitable method. Thanks!

I want something like this:

```
data(mtcars)
$mpg 
mean median st
20.09 19.2 6.03
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apply multiple functions in sapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053266/apply-multiple-functions-in-sapply)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `{dplyr}` provides a very nice way of doing this with `across()`:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
    summarise(across(mpg, list(mean = mean, median = median, sd = sd)))
#>   mpg_mean mpg_median   mpg_sd
#> 1 20.09062       19.2 6.026948
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is with `summary`:

```
summary(mtcars$mpg)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.40   15.43   19.20   20.09   22.80   33.90
```

Alternatively, you could use `sapply` and give this a list of functions:

```
sapply(list(mean = mean, median = median, sd = sd), function(x, y) x(y), mtcars$mpg)
     mean    median        sd 
20.090625 19.200000  6.026948
```

Here, `x` refers to the function in the `list`, and `y` is the `mtcars` column. The final argument is just the actual column you want your function to apply to.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Inside my function, F(df, j), I changed mtcars$mpg to df[,j] to be able to call F(mtcars, 1). If I want my function to return a list of mean, median and sd of any two variables in mtcars (not one column at a time), how would I go about doing this? Thanks again.

Comment: The answer from @Park is a good way of doing all of them at once. Otherwise, if you just want a subset of them you could do this maybe (for mpg and hp, for example):  `lapply(mtcars[, c("mpg", "hp")], function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), median = median(x)))`. Or you could just subset down the `mtcars` dataframe to just the columns you want and use @Park's `apply` solution.

Answer (score 3):

You may try

```
mtcars_summary <- apply(mtcars, 2, function(x){
  c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), med = median(x))
}) 

           mpg      cyl     disp        hp      drat        wt      qsec        vs        am      gear   carb
mean 20.090625 6.187500 230.7219 146.68750 3.5965625 3.2172500 17.848750 0.4375000 0.4062500 3.6875000 2.8125
sd    6.026948 1.785922 123.9387  68.56287 0.5346787 0.9784574  1.786943 0.5040161 0.4989909 0.7378041 1.6152
med  19.200000 6.000000 196.3000 123.00000 3.6950000 3.3250000 17.710000 0.0000000 0.0000000 4.0000000 2.0000
```