# What's a shorthand for `across(everything(), ...)` in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I'm wondering if there's an obvious shorthand for applying a bunch of functions across the whole dataset, that is shorthand for `across(everything(), ...)`. Solution does not have to use dplyr.

Note that

```r
! Using `across()` without supplying `.cols` was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
```

Example

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars |> summarize(across(everything(), list(min, max)))
```

The end goal is something like this use case (but not only):

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars |> 
  summarize(across(everything(), lst(min, max))) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c("var", ".value"), names_sep = "_")

# A tibble: 11 × 3
   var     min    max
   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 mpg   10.4   33.9 
 2 cyl    4      8   
 3 disp  71.1  472   
 4 hp    52    335   
 5 drat   2.76   4.93
 6 wt     1.51   5.42
 7 qsec  14.5   22.9 
 8 vs     0      1   
 9 am     0      1   
10 gear   3      5   
11 carb   1      8   
>
```

(NB: `dplyr::lst()` gives you correct names.)

Comment: Try `sapply(mtcars, function(i) c(min(i), max(i)))`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053266/apply-multiple-functions-in-sapply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shorthand for

`across(everything(), ...)`

is

`across(,...)`

in `dplyr`

Comment: Yes I missed the comma -- should we delete the question? Maybe there's sth else that's interesting though.

Comment: I would suggest to keep the question. It is a interesting question and not obvious!