# A concise way in R to count unique values in each dataframe column, by group?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (suppose it has a large number of columns) which I would like to group by a given column.  I would then like the output of my script to be a new dataframe or tibble, with one row for each group in the original df, and each subsequent column contains a numeric value corresponding to the number of unique values in that column *for that group*.  Other than the "group by" column, it's not feasible for me to reference columns explicitly in the script.  My current script accomplishes this with a for loop, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient or elegant way to do it?  I suspect my half-dozen lines could probably be re-written faster and more concisely, but I'm not very adept at R yet.

Previous questions asked on this topic involve only two columns, and/or explicitly referencing individual column names, or involve data.tables (which I'd prefer to avoid unless it makes things super-elegant), or otherwise don't work in my scenario.  But if this is a duplicate, my apologies.

Example:

```
# my real df has many more columns than this
df <- data.frame(my_group=c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'),
                 age=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,8,9),
                 gender=c(1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2),
                 x=c(T,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F))

# separate the df into a list of smaller dfs, organized by group
t <- split(df[,colnames(df)!="my_group"], df$my_group)

results <- df[FALSE,] # prepare a template to bind new rows to

for ( i in 1:length(t)) {  #eeeww, a for loop
  z <- rapply(t[[i]], function(x) length(unique(unlist(x))))
  row <- data.frame(my_group=names(t[i]),t(data.frame(z)))
  results <- rbind(results, row, make.row.names=FALSE)
}
```

output:

```
> results
  my_group age gender x
1        a   2      2 2
2        b   3      2 1
3        c   3      1 2
# correct, but slow and perhaps not very "r"-ish
```

I made various attempts with group_by() and nested apply() calls, but I could never quite get what I was aiming for.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Update 1:**

Thank you AkselA, Samet Sökel, TarJae, Umar, Murad Khalilov and all future contributors!  There were several excellent answers and it was hard to pick the ultimate one.  In the end, I found these three solutions to work best for me.  The last two combine some of the suggested answers into individual one-liners.

```
df %>% group_by(my_group) %>% summarise_all(n_distinct) #fastest, Samet Sökel
summarize(df, across(everything(), n_distinct), .by=my_group) #relative speed 1.12; TarJae, Umar
aggregate(. ~ my_group, data = df, n_distinct) #relative speed 1.022; AkselA, TarJae, Umar, Samet Sökel
```

**Update 2:**
I have noted that the aggregate() method fails if there are NAs in the dataframe, irrespective of including `na.action = na.omit`, use with caution.  Also, I updated "Update 1" with the relative speed benchmarks on my system (n=1, not scientific, heh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `n_distinct` and `summarise_all` together

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(my_group=c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'),
                 age=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,8,9),
                 gender=c(1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2),
                 x=c(T,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F))

df %>% group_by(my_group) %>% summarise_all(n_distinct)


my_group   age gender     x
  <chr>    <int>  <int> <int>
1 a            2      2     2
2 b            3      2     1
3 c            3      1     2
```

Comment: Thank you, I like that it is a concise 1-liner with dplyr.

Comment: This is a 2-liner in one line. :-)  this is a 1- liner: `summarize(df, across(everything(), n_distinct), .by=my_group)`

Comment: Ah I guess you are right on that point :)  '2-in-1'-liner works too hehe

Comment: @TarJae I think pipe operator can be assumed as 1-liner :D `summarise_all(group_by(df,my_group),n_distinct)`

Comment: @SametSökel It is not important. Note the :-) smile in my comment!!!

Comment: mine also has smile :) have a great day

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for `aggregate()`

```
nunique <- function(v) length(unique(v))
aggregate(cbind(age, gender, x) ~ my_group, nunique, data=df)
#   my_group age gender x
# 1        a   2      2 2
# 2        b   3      2 1
# 3        c   3      1 2
```

Eve more succinct (all columns except the grouping column)

```
aggregate(. ~ my_group, nunique, data=df)
#   my_group age gender x
# 1        a   2      2 2
# 2        b   3      2 1
# 3        c   3      1 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I like that this is concise and doesn't require additional libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the dplyr and tidyr packages in R. Use group_by function from dplyr to group the data by the my_group column and then uses summarize along with across(everything(), ~ length(unique(.))) to apply the counting of unique values to all columns in the grouped data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(my_group) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ length(unique(.))))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  my_group   age gender     x
  <chr>    <int>  <int> <int>
1 a            2      2     2
2 b            3      2     1
3 c            3      1     2
```

or in your code u can make smoe small chnges. I used bind_rows to concatenate the results for each group within the loop. U can  count unique values in each column by using across within the summarise function.

```
# Separate the df into a list of smaller dfs, organized by group
t <- split(df[,colnames(df)!="my_group"], df$my_group)

# Initialize results
results <- data.frame(my_group = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through the list and apply counting using across
for (i in seq_along(t)) {
  result_row <- t[[i]] %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ length(unique(.)))) %>%
    mutate(my_group = names(t)[i])
  
  results <- bind_rows(results, result_row)
}

print(results)

    (results)
      my_group age gender x
    1        a   2      2 2
    2        b   3      2 1
    3        c   3      1 2
```

another way is

```
df %>%
  group_by(my_group) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ n_distinct(.)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the multiple methods.  I found that I did not have to separately load tidyr.  By adapting TarJae's first example to your first example, I have:
`df %>% summarize(across(everything(), ~ length(unique(.))), .by=my_group)`
I also appreciate the suggestions for my for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using for loop within apply is not reccommeded way to have, there are lots of way to create your result according to your dataframe, but I would suggest two way to boost speed.

```
# Load libraries
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, vctrs, data.table)

# create data
df <- data.frame(my_group=c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'),
                 age=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,8,9),
                 gender=c(1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2),
                 x=c(T,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F))
```

1st solution: using simple tidyverse group by
but tidyverse pipeline is also slow if you are working huge number of records, therefore, it is better to refer vctrs library, and use vec_unique_count() function which change columns to vector (vectors are faster way to process) and counting unique values same as length(unique())

```
df %>% 
  group_by(my_group) %>% 
  summarize(
    age = vec_unique_count(age),
    gender = vec_unique_count(gender),
    x = vec_unique_count(x)
    
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

2nd solution: using data.table package

if you are not happy with speed yet, then for big data, use data.table syntax, it is considerable faster than others. you can use data.table function uniqueN as well, but I believe for big data vctrs functions slightly better

```
as.data.table(df)[, .(
  age = vec_unique_count(age), # uniqueN()
  gender = vec_unique_count(gender), # uniqueN()
  x = vec_unique_count(x) # uniqueN()
), .(my_group)]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not very familiar with the vctrs library but I will start learning it for the large data speed benefit!

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, the only new aspect of this question may be performing the distinct count over multiple columns, which can be achieved using `across` as already mentioned by @Limey in the comments. I have added some alternatives.

##### `base R`

```
aggregate(. ~ my_group, data = df, \(x) length(unique(x)))
```

##### `dplyr > 1.1.0`

```
library(dplyr)

summarize(df, across(, n_distinct), .by=my_group)
```

##### `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, lapply(.SD, \(x) length(unique(x))), by = my_group]
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the presentation of multiple methods. I will have to start learning about data tables.

I modified your dplyr solution because as-is, it throws a warning for not specifying .cols in the call to across(). I can avoid this by adapting @Umar's 3rd example.  I also like that the across(.cols=) can be manipulated for selectivity easily.
`summarize(df, across(everything(), n_distinct), .by=my_group)`

Comment: Yous should update dplyr. Then it will throw no error. It is quite new to use .by=... instead of group_by(...). Cheers!

Comment: I just updated 1.1.2->1.1.4, thanks for the reminder :)  Unfortunately, it did not clear the warning in the original method.  `Using 'across()' without supplying '.cols' was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.  Please supply '.cols' instead.` (verified the new library was loaded.  Do you still get it if you reset your warning lifecycle? By the way, I did not know about the \\(x) short-hand for anonymous functions before your example, so thanks for that too.

Comment: Ah ok. that is an "insider" see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74552567/whats-a-shorthand-for-acrosseverything-in-dplyr). Unfortunately the will stop this!. just use `everything()`.